# Filter/group records in Salesforce related lists by value

Tags: page-layout, related-list

In SF related lists, how can we filter records by values ? 
On Company page layout, we will have Contact related list once filter by one value and
Contact related list second time filter by another value; works ?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi @ISB. There are a few issues with your question here. It isn't very clear what you are looking to do. You also did not provide a very clear title. I see you tagged it as salesforce2salesforce, do you have a reason for that? That doesn't seem to be related at all. Please read up on the proper way to ask questions here - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask - and some feedback from the community - http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273/tips-and-tricks-for-asking-a-good-question

Answer (score 1):

I am taking a "best guess" at what your question is:

> You want to add the Contact related list onto your Company page layout
>   twice. Each time you do that, you want to "filter" by a different
>   value.

Well, first off, you can not filter related lists. There is an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bqu5AAC) for similar functionality if you would like to vote on it. Secondly, you can not add the same related list onto a page layout twice. There is really no point to ever do that currently as they will both display the same information.

To do what you want to do, you need to add custom Visualforce/Apex.

Comment: You got my question correct; we need to display contacts separately on Company page by Contact Type. How about related lookup filter option; is that something different or we can use it somehow to meet my usecase, thx.

Comment: Can you please edit your original question to make it more clear?